# How to call base class method from super class method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

my base `class`:

```js
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { Feature } from './super.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent extends Feature {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  superToCall(value) {
    console.log('value', value);
  }
}
```

super `class`:

```
export class Feature {
  childCalled(value) {
    console.log('child called', value);
  }
}
```

how to pass the param to `superToCall` from `childCalled` method?

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zfqrye?file=src/app/super.component.ts)

Comment: Component inheritance is a bad practice and should be avoided instead try using a composition patterns.

Comment: Having said that what you are trying to achieve can be done, what is the problem you are facing? Just call the base method with params.

Comment: @VimalPatel how to do with `composition patterns` can you post your code fo the same

Comment: getting an error as `Property 'superToCall' does not exist on type 'Feature'.(2339)`

Comment: error is correct, in your base class method name is `childCalled` so you should invoke that method.

Comment: I would like to pass paras to child, need to call `superToCall`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your parent class (`Feature`) abstract and add an abstract function `superToCall` (which the children must implement):

```js
export abstract class Feature {
  childCalled(value) {
    console.log('child called', value);
    this.superToCall(value);
  }

  abstract superToCall(value);
}
```

All children (which extend `Feature`) must now implement the abstract method `superToCall`:

```js
export class AppComponent extends Feature {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  override superToCall(value) {
    console.log('value', value);
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-da7adu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsuper.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: what is mean to declare override? without even it's works. 9x angular thows error on override

Comment: Override only exists since typescript 4.3, so it may not work in oder Angular versions. If possible you should always use it, because it can help you find errors: i.e. when you change the code later: see [typescript 4.3 override](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#override-and-the---noimplicitoverride-flag)

Answer (score 2):

Classic OOP pattern: declare super class as abstract with abstract method `abstract superToCall(value: unknown):void`. Now you can call child's method from parent class with `this.superToCall(someValue)`

```js
export abstract class Feature {
  childCalled(value: unknown) {
    console.log('child called', value);
    this.superToCall(value);
  }
 abstract superToCall(value: any): void;
}

export class AppComponent extends Feature {
  superToCall(value: any) {
    console.log('value', value);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you update my code please? not clearly getting

Answer (score -1):

This is helped me:

```
ParentClass.prototype.myMethod.call(this)
```

call with params:

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

export class Feature {
  childCalled(value) {
    AppComponent.prototype.superToCall.call(this, value)
  }
}
```